# Error in YAML when knitting RMarkdown document

Tags: r-markdown

When I try to knit a RMarkdown document to PDF I get the following error message:

Error in packageVersion("yaml") : package 'yaml' not found
Calls:  ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load_utf8 -> packageVersion
Execution halted

I`ve tried to reinstall the yaml package several times without success. I have also load yaml explicitly with the lib.loc. I also get the same yaml error when i try to knit to html.